# IDEA - "Import from external model" vs "Create from existing source"?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

In IDEA 11, what is the difference between "Import project from external model" and "Create project from existing source"?

[image]

I've tested both features on existing code (counted num of files created and size increase) and it seems that both features do the same thing.

So what is the golden rule on when to use the first and when the second feature?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With "Import project from external model" option, you will have the possibility to import an existing project which was created in a different model. Like Eclipse or Maven project, etc. IntelliJ IDEA will interpret the project files (i.e. you eclipse project will be migrated to IDEA).

The "Create project from existing sources" option, will just create the IDEA project over an existing source code.

There is no golden rule. It's just simply which case you need. If you have an Eclipse or Maven project and you want to load it with IDEA then use "Import project from external model".

Otherwise, if you have just a bunch of source code and you want to start fast, then use "Create project from existing sources".

Comment: What is an idea project ?

Comment: Its an intellij project