# Pull Eclipse project from GitHub to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a newbie and just started an Android project using Eclipse and GitHub. I'd like to move my project to Android Studio.

When I pull the project from GitHub to Android Studio, it asks me these choices: 
1) Create project from existing sources
2) Import project from external models (with two choices: Gradle or Maven)

What's the difference between these options?

Comment: Refer to this questions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258321/idea-import-from-external-model-vs-create-from-existing-source

Comment: Thanks for showing the link. It's true there's no golden rule for choosing one of these options.